# material-ui TreeView (from Lab) incorrectly aligns 3rd + child node

Tags: material-ui

https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/
https://codesandbox.io/s/ujp8m

looking at material-ui example above - if a Category.Social.TestNode is added to the data, the TestNode child node is incorrectly positioned under its parent Social node. It should be moved over to the right i.e. displayed as child. Because this is still Lab not too worried but would like to know where to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and found a sort of solution ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9h136?fontsize=14))

Basically I pass a depth css property (`--node-depth`) which is used to calculate how much padding an element must have `` paddingLeft: `calc(var(--node-depth) * ${theme.spacing(2)}px)` ``

The depth is set at `StyledTreeItem` where I iterate over every child to pass depth as prop to the nested elements (depht by default is 0):

```
React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, { depth: depth + 1 });
})
```

I hope this helps.